# Is there a way to include the sum of all cases?

Tags: mysql

**Given SQL:** Is there a way to bring in the total of the result set?

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN status = 3 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS Open,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN status = 4 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS Close
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    id = 2;
```

**Result:**

```
Open,Close
5,5
```

**Desired Result:**

```
Open,Close,Total
5,5,10
```

Comment: Note that in MySQL, you can use SUM(status=4) instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add another case statement

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN status = 3 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS Open,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN status = 4 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS Close
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN status IN (3, 4) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS Total
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    id = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE:

```
WITH sumCase AS (
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN status = 3 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS Open,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN status = 4 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS Close
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    id = 2;)
SELECT Open,Close, Open + Close AS Total FROM Table1;
```

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/

Answer (score 0):

using sub-query

```
   select open,close,open+close as total from
    (
       SELECT 
        SUM(CASE  WHEN status = 3 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
             END ) AS Open,
       SUM(CASE   WHEN status = 4 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END) AS Close
    FROM
    Table1
    WHERE   id = 2   ) as T
```